# Java 9 options --add-exports vs. -XaddExports not recognized

Tags: java, java-9

I downloaded the latest jdk9 build:

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+142)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 9-ea+142, mixed mode)
```

When I execute

```
/path/jdk-9/bin/java -X
```

I see the option:

```
--add-exports <module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
                  updates <module> to export <package> to <target-module>,
                  regardless of module declaration.
                  <target-module> can be ALL-UNNAMED to export to all
                  unnamed modules.
```

But when I try to use this option:

```
/path/jdk-9/bin/java --add-exports:java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -jar some.jar
```

I get:

```
Unrecognized option: --add-exports:java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
```

The same for `-XaddExports` which I saw in some posts.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Do I need a special jigsaw jdk9 distribution? I'm a bit confused about the different jdk9 versions to be honest ;)

Comment: Why `--add-exports:java.base/...`? I'd expect `--add-exports java.base/...` (space)

Comment: Ah, will try. I used this because I saw this for the old option -XaddExports https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2016/08/09/jigsaw-maven-integration.html

Comment: Oh, my this was it! Please feel free to add this as the answer! Thanks a bunch! I was messing around already for some hours ;(

Comment: @Tunaki not sure if you also get pings without explicit mentioing ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two flags have slightly different syntax.  At some point (I think it was build 9-ea+113) where the JVM switched over from `-XaddExports` to the `--add-exports` syntax, as part of the effort for [JEP 293](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/293) which aims to achieve GNU-style syntax for command line arguments.

**Current syntax:**

```
--add-exports <module>/<module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
--add-reads <module>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
```

*Note:* Some utilities may have trouble accepting the new `--key value` style of arguments because there is a space between them, in that case you can put also put an equals sign in the middle (i.e. `--key=value`) to satisfy those utilities.

**Old syntax:**

```
-XaddExports:<module>/<module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
-XaddReads:<module>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*
```

Unfortunately, it's very easy to miss the space to colon change.  I've messed it up several times myself.